# Heroku: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed a rails application with a `database.yml` file as follows

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  host: localhost
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: '*****'
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: VenJob_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: VenJob_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: VenJob_production
  username: VenJob
  password: <%= ENV['VENJOB_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

when i run `heroku run rails db:migrate`  i get error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
......
Caused by:
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
.....
```

please guide me to fix this problem

Comment: `host` is set to `localhost` in default, so you need to remove that and add proper `host` or `database_url` in production.

Comment: You can't run a MySQL server on the local machine on Heroku. Instead, pick an appropriate [addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) (or host your own database elsewhere if you prefer). If you use an addon, you'll automatically get an environment variable you can use to connect.